# Simple SceneKit scene shows black screen instead of SCNPlane

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am getting my feet wet with iOS SceneKit, however the following sample code (which executes inside `viewDidLoad`) is not behaving as expected. I want it to

1. place a camera at origin with direction of view towards positive z axis
2. place a red rectangle parallel to xy-plane at z = 100

Why does the rendering not reveal the red rectangle but only a black screen?

```
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // prepare camera

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    camera.zNear =  90
    camera.zFar  = 110

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, Float(M_PI))
    cameraNode.camera   = camera

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // prepare light

    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type  = SCNLightTypeOmni
    light.color = SKColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)

    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light;

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // prepare plane

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 400, height: 400)
    plane.firstMaterial!.doubleSided      = true
    plane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 100)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

    // prepare view as SCNView

    let sceneView = view as SCNView

    sceneView.backgroundColor  = SKColor.blackColor()
    sceneView.scene            = scene
    sceneView.delegate         = self
    sceneView.jitteringEnabled = true // i.e. improve visual rendering
    sceneView.pointOfView      = cameraNode
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you rotate around the x axis instead of the y axis (so that the camera looks in the desired direction)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: rotating the camera around the wrong axis can make some objects not visible. Which leads to a black screen.

Comment: Hmm ... if I want to rotate the direction of view from -z to +z, doesn't both a rotation by 180 degree around either the x or z axis amount to the same thing (see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vCVR1.png))?

Comment: oh it's a rotation by pi, not pi/2. So yes both lead to the same result. Sorry for that. I've tested your code on iOS and OS X and in both cases I see a shaded red plane.

Comment: +1 for testing my code. I was being foolish in mistaking a relatively dark/dim red for black. If you edit your answer such that it mentions the testing (i.e. such that it makes sense to later readers), I'll be happy to accept it.